# How to add vibrancy effect to UISegmentedControl but not to its labels?

Tags: ios8, uivibrancyeffect

In notification centre, the top segmented control looks to be drawn with a vibrancy effect. However, its labels (Today and Notifications) appear to be regular, opaque colours. How can I reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

First, Add **UISegmentedControl** to **UIVisualEffectView**, the one with vibrancy.

Then, Add another Identical **UISegmentedControl** just above the Previous Segmented Control but not in the same view, a view above or anywhere.

Set the ***TintColor*** of The ***upperSegmentedControl*** to `UIColor.clearcolor()`

Set ***UserInteractionEnabled*** to ***false***

And then,

```
upperSegmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

upperSegmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.clearColor()], forState: UIControlState.Selected)
```

### Important NOTE : Keep both segments in sync.

This is not the Smartest Solution, But it works.